# accessing same MySQL database from different pc gives me an error

Tags: mysql

I have a Mysql Server with a Database, installed on a PC and there are two copies of application (Inventory System) running on the same PC and another PC. both copies of application access same database server.

In the Application, to add new **Invoice Record** we need to insert a new record to `invoice` table and get the last Inv_Id, then we can inset invoice items details under that ID to `invoice_items` table,

so i used this query to get Last added ID

```
Select Inv_Id From Invoice Order By Inv_ID DESC Limit 1
```

this work perfectly if only running single copy of the application, when both copies try to insert a **Invoice record** at the same time,

```
Select Inv_Id From Invoice Order By Inv_ID DESC Limit 1
```

this not return anything.

Is there any configuration to do `MySQL Server` to fix that issue?

Comment: did you wrap the whole insert procedure with a transaction?

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff No